# Delete [copyright-law] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

I just came across the [copyright-law](/questions/tagged/copyright-law) tag on SO. I don't think this tag belongs to SO, as all these questions are off-topic and should get asked on [Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: While these may all be good for Patents, I'm not sure they're off-topic for [SO].

Comment: Just the opposite. I doubt any of them would be good for Patents, and they're definitely off-topic on Stack Overflow.